# Is there analogy of function MapIndexed (Map) for Nest?

Tags: functions, function-construction

We have `Map` and its upgraded variant `MapIndexed`.
Is there analogy for `Nest`? I know there is no `NestIndexed` in Mathematica in recent versions but I mean if it is possible to imitate it by elegant combination of other functions.

My solution with using `n++` bellow I do not regard as elegant.

```
Map[f, {a, b, c, d}]
MapIndexed[f, {a, b, c, d}]

n = 1;
Nest[f[#, n++] &, k, 4]
Clear[n]

(* {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d]} *)
(* {f[a, {1}], f[b, {2}], f[c, {3}], f[d, {4}]} *)

(* f[f[f[f[k, 1], 2], 3], 4] *)
```

Comment: I don't see using `n++` as inelegant - if this were a built-in function it would do something similar

Comment: Maybe `Fold[f,k,Range[4]]`. Or `Nest[{f@@#,#[[2]]+1}&,{k,1},4][[1]]`.

Comment: dang it! just beat me to it @user293787

Comment: @user293787: That's it! It was something in my mind that was telling me there is a similar function but could not recall it. If there is no better solution I would accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One could use [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html):

```
Fold[f,k,Range[4]]
(* f[f[f[f[k,1],2],3],4] *)
```

Alternatively, one could use [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) using pairs where the first entry contains the evaluations of `f` and the second entry is the index:

```
Nest[{f@@#,Last[#]+1}&,{k,1},4][[1]]
(* f[f[f[f[k,1],2],3],4] *)
```

Comment: I like the version with `Fold`.